# File utility including UPnP/DLNA resources - like BubbleUPnP on Android?

Tags: android, filemanager, dlna, upnp

I'm looking for a file utility that supports UPnP/DLNA resources.
There are PLAYERS, but I want to have the media preferably visible in a combined file utility/manager (like Windows Explorer), or its own (like  Android BubleUPnP).
Dolphin allows for ssh, ftp, etc., but not DLNA.

My research provided djmount, but that seems to be unavailable in 22.04.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted, this is exactly what I'm looking for too ... and thanks for the reference for `djmount`